# sending a post request from firefox addon

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am currently working on an addon and it had a addon window with addon buttons and a tab in main window it maintains. I am able to open a page in main tab by

```
mainWindow().location = "http://murmuring-retreat-7618.herokuapp.com/signin";
```

I created mainWindow by following way

```
getBrowser().getBrowserForTab(bridge.recordingTab).contentWindow;
```

where I have already saved bridge.recordingTab as the tab I am connected.

but if I want to send a post request instead of just open a url, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery in your firefox addon then you could simply do a [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

**Note** though that you need the destination server to be [CORS enabled](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), otherwise you can only do `JSONP` requests using [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: how do I post from the mainwindow? should I do something like mainWindow().post?